# TempDB Query being Blocked

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, blocking

I have been monitoring Blocking issues on our SQL Server database. Very often the below query is running on tempdb and is blocked with LCK_M_S

What is this query used for and why does it run regularly?

Thanks!

```
<?query --
select @reservedpages = sum(a.total_pages),
    @usedpages = sum(a.used_pages),
    @pages = sum(
            CASE
                -- XML-Index and FT-Index internal tables are not considered "data", but is part of "index_size"
                When it.internal_type IN (202,204,211,212,213,214,215,216) Then 0
                When a.type <> 1 Then a.used_pages
                When p.index_id < 2 Then a.data_pages
                Else 0
            END
        )
from sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id
    left join sys.internal_tables it on p.object_id = it.object_id

    /* unallocated space could not be negative */

--?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is from a system stored procedure called `sp_spaceused`, which returns the amount of allocated space (pages) for database objects.

Look for home-brewn monitoring jobs or maintenance scripts that may be running a bit too frequently.